# Can I opt-out classes from Appearance API?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, appearance

When I define UIView’s background color by

`UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = .red`

How can I opt-out specific UIView’s in this project?

Because `someView.backgroundColor = .green` gets overridden.

Comment: By using UIView.apperance(), you are telling the system to respect that color throughout the application.  If you want to use different colours then I would not recommend doing this.  Better to set the backgroundColor on your views either separately, or create custom subclasses with different backgroundColors.

Comment: Any subclass of UIView also adopts this backgroundColor. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I meant set the backgroundColor in your subclass as needed - do not use the global setting.